# Two Select Queries on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to find an answer to this issue.

I have a table where I can have multiple order ids for one customer (email)

```
email (unique), order_id
```

I need to make a query where I pass in any order_id for a customer, and it returns ALL their orders.

I have two select queries I need to combine into one query to save on load time.

```
SELECT email FROM orders WHERE order_id = '1234567890'

SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE email = 'email_found_from_first_query'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select o.order_id
from orders o
where o.email = (select o2.email from orders o2 where order_id = '1234567890')
```

Comment: But you don't use `exists` in your query. And it would be inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

An old school way of using in can be used here:

```
SELECT order_id 
FROM orders 
WHERE email IN (
                SELECT email 
                FROM orders 
                WHERE order_id = '1234567890'
                )
```

query is little expensive.

Comment: Why would you use IN for a subquery which returns one row only.

Answer (score 0):

This seems best suited for a simple JOIN. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

```sql
SELECT orig_order.email, all_orders.order_id
FROM orders as orig_order
JOIN orders as all_orders ON orig_order.email = all_orders.email
WHERE orig_order.order_id = '1234567890'
```